# Visual Studio 2013 reordering tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

Every time I run my code on VS2013, my tabs get rearranged alphabetically and I have no idea why. I have Resharper 8.2 installed, I went through the settings but found nothing too evident that's messing with the tabs.

Has anyone seen and / or solved this problem? Any extra info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have Productivity Power Tools (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) there is feature in there that sorts tabs alphabetically.  Look in tools\options\Productivity Power Tools for an option to disable that, or remove/disable Productivity Power Tools

Comment: That worked! I had no idea my VS had those tools installed, it must've come with the Windows image we all got. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13):

A pretty annoying feature from Productivity Power Tools extension.

In Visual Studio 2015 you can turn it off in following:

```
Menu
 -> Tools
  -> Options
   -> Productivity Power Tools
     -> Turn off "Custom Document Well"
  or -> Custom Document Well, uncheck Sorting Alphabetically
```

[image: screenshot of sorting settings]

Comment: Thanks for that exact path to the option!